# How many values a polynomial map misses? 

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, open-problems

Let $F$ be a field. For a uni-variate polynomial $f(x)$ over $F$,let $M_f(F)$ denote the number of values that $f$ misses, that is, the cardinality of the subset $F - f(F)$ in $F$. Assume that $f$ is not 
surjective, that is, $M_f(F) > 0$. Is the number $M_f(F)$ big?

If $F = {\mathbb F}_q$ is a finite field of $q$ elements and $f\in \mathbb{F}_q[x]$ is a polynomial of degree $d>0$, then a simple 
result shows that if $M_f(F_q) > 0$, then 
$$M_f(F_q) \geq \frac{q-1}{d}. $$
As $q$ goes to infinity, this lower bound goes to infinity. 
This suggests the following question for which I do not know the answer.

Question. Assume that $F$ is an infinite field. If $M_f(F)>0$. 
Is it true that $M_f(F) = \infty$? 
In other words, for an infinite field $F$, if $f \in F[x]$ misses one value, is it true that $f$ misses infinitely many values?

The answer is positive if $F$ is big in the sense that F is algebraically closed (${\mathbb C}$ etc), or topologically closed 
($\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{Q}_p$ etc) or if $F$ is a small field such as a Hilbertian field (number fields etc). Anyone has more 
examples or counter-examples?

Gjergji-Zaimi points out that the above question has been asked before, see 
[Can a non-surjective polynomial map from an infinite field to itself miss only finitely many points?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6820/can-a-non-surjective-polynomial-map-from-an-infinite-field-to-itself-miss-only-fi)

To make my question somewhat newer, I will ask a multi-variable version 
of the question. It is unknown to me even in the case that the 
field is the complex numbers.

Question: Assume that $f=(f_1,..., f_n): F^n -> F^n$ is a FINITE  polynomial map in n variables over an infinite field F. If f misses one value, is it true that f misses infinitely many values?

I do not know the answer even in the case when $F={\mathbb C}$ is 
the complex numbers if $n \geq 2$. Note that the finiteness assumption of the map $f$ cannot be dropped, as Kharlamov (2012) has given the example 
$$f=(u(uv-1), u^2-(uv-1)^2)$$
which misses precisely one point, the origin (0,0) of ${\mathbb C}^2$.

Comment: This question has appeared before with no actual answer http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6820/can-a-non-surjective-polynomial-map-from-an-infinite-field-to-itself-miss-only-fi

Comment: So should this be closed as essentially a duplicate of MO6820?

Comment: Note that when I asked a related question, Bjorn gave a non-rigorous argument that there should be counterexamples. I think that "no actual answer" is too pessimistic; one can conjecture with evidence that the answer is no.  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/9863/when-fx-a-and-fx-b-yield-the-same-field-extension

Comment: I have updated this question with a multi-variate version, 
which seems newer, even in the case when the field F is the complex numbers. 

Comment: This question is a special case of a problem which has been open for four decades:  Is an infinite field $K$ for which every definable set $X \subseteq K$ is finite or cofinite [called a ``minimal field''] necessarily algebraically closed?  See Podewski, Minimale Ringe, Math. Phys. Semesterber 22 (1975), no. 2, 193 – 197.   It is known that a counterexample must have characteristic zero:  Wagner, Minimal fields,  J. Symbolic Logic 65 (2000), no. 4, 1833 – 1835. 

Comment: Thomas Scanlon - it seems to me you could post your comment as an answer.

Comment: Thomas Scanlon: I do not see how Podewski's conjecture implies an answer to my question. My confusion is that for my field F, I usually have a polynomial f such that its value set f(F) (a definable subset of F) is neither finite nor co-finite and 
thus the field F is not minimal. For example, as you mention that 
Podewski's conjecture is true in positive characteristic. 
What this implies for my value gap question when F is an infinite algebraic extension of a finite field, the case of most interest 
to me. Can you explain in more detail? 